# How to disable page based on database(firebase) query?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to react  and  firebase and currently developing and application as  my final year project

**PROBLEM:**

There are two pages in my application  **PAGE 1 & PAGE2** ,
I want to disable PAGE 1 until PAGE 2 is data entered (Should check only intial record when app is installed )

**CODE:**

**CODE INSIDE PAGE 1**

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${awcid}/Timeline/Page2/`)
     .orderByChild('Page2date')
     .limitToLast(1)
     .once('value', checkifexists => {
       const datafff = firebaseLooper(checkifexists);
       console.log("checkifexists", datafff.length);
        const temp=datafff.length;
       if ((temp >= 1)) {
         this.setState({
           checkifexists: temp
         });
         console.log( "--------checkifexists--------","IF CONDITION",this.state.checkifexists, "----------------");
       } else {
         this.setState({
           checkifexists: 0
         });
         console.log("ELSE CONDITION");
       }
     });
}
```

***INSIDE RENDER***

```
   {!(parseInt(this.state.checkifexists) >= parseInt(1)) ? 
 <View style={styles.notexists} >
<Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', textAlign: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>Please enter stock page initially to access this page{'\n'}</Text>
</View> :
         :<View><Text>Display the form</Text></View>}
```

This code works fine but it checks everytime when page1 is loaded ***(instead of checking initially)***

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a flag to identify if the app is running for the first time after installation. You can use [react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage) to store a field as 'isNotFrsttime' and set it to true after the first run. Also make sure to include that boolean check to block your views only for initial app run.

Or else if you are using redux you can persist your redux state and rehydrate on app launch. You can store your flag in redux if you already implemented redux in your project.